# ASP.Net Core JavaScript Engine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, three.js, .net-core

I'm working on the project using `ASP.Net Core` (`.NetCoreApp 1.1`) + `SpaServices` + `React` + `Redux` + `Webpack`. The true power of React is a server-side JS rendering. Everything works fine when you use `IIS`/`Kestrel` with popular JS libraries, but the server-side rendering breaks down when you try using some UI libraries.

I use `react-planner` in my project and it depends on 'three' lib that provides WebGL and canvas renderers. The problem is that Asp.Net Core default JS engine doesn't have a 'window' environment that is available in browser on client-side, so the server can't render some JS libs. There is a library for `.Net` called `JavaScriptEngineSwitcher`, but it doesn't support `.NetCoreApp`. I see 3 ways right now:

1. Find a way to switch default JS engine.
2. Disable server-side rendering.
3. Find a way to switch-off server-side rendering for `react-planner` only.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure *any* javascript engines support `window`.  `window` is the global for a browser.  I would look towards option 3 and detect whether you are server-side rendering or not.

Comment: There is an explicit option on the main page of the app that defines whether to use the server-side rendering or not. I don't know how to use the server-side rendering only for a couple of components and I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a library for .Net called JavaScriptEngineSwitcher, but it doesn't support .NetCoreApp.

This problem is solved in the [JavaScript Engine Switcher version 2.X](https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher/wiki/How-to-upgrade-applications-to-version-2.X) and React.NET version 3.X.

Quote from documentation:

> If you create a web application based on the “ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)” template, then you will have only four JS engines: [JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore](https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher/wiki/JS-Engine-Switcher:-ChakraCore), [JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie](https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher/wiki/JS-Engine-Switcher:-MSIE) (only works in JsRT modes), [JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Jint](https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher/wiki/JS-Engine-Switcher:-Jint) and [JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Vroom](https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher/wiki/JS-Engine-Switcher:-Vroom).

And now about the `window` object:

> The problem is that Asp.Net Core default JS engine doesn't have a 'window' environment that is available in browser on client-side, so the server can't render some JS libs.

The `window` object is not part of the ECMAScript specification, because it is a DOM object. Most likely, in your code there is a line of the following kind:

```
var root = typeof global !== 'undefined' ? global : window;
```

To execute your code on the server, you can replace this line with the following code:

```
var global = this; // this line should be placed at the beginning of script
…
var root = global
```